# Reversing Contactless Chip Capabilities

Tags: communication

I have a contactless card which I'd like to know the capabilities. I assume the card works with NFC. However standard tools (*nfc-list*) do not seem to be able to retrieve regular informations from it (not even the UID), the phone can't detect it either. This may be because the chip may have a not common NFC type.

Now my question is: how can I know what kind of chip technology this is so I can begin working on understanding how data is stored and what is the protocol ?

What kind of additional hardware other than a simple reader (e.g ACR122U) may come handy to identify the card ?